# How can I Add a Horizontal UIScrollView So I can View Text on iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I am creating an app that lets you fill your Info 
for Example:" Your Name : John " etc…

So i have made many question but they dont Fit in the Screen. I want to add a UIScroll View so I can Scroll Down and ask more questions.

Thank You

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: i have everything on IB , i just need to add more space for more questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this example should help you

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/tutorial/iphone/UIScrollView-Example-iPhone.html

you can use label instead of UITextField here..